# How do you read a textfile into an array python

Tags: python

Could anyone tell me how to read a text file to an array in python?

The text file looks like the following:

```
Apples,78
Pears,45
Oranges,99
Grapes,44
```

The array should be the following:

```
Fruit=[Apples,78],[Pears,45],[Oranges,99],Grapes,44]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in one line :

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print([i.strip().split(',') for i in f])
```

Comment: this is really nice. Maybe the OP needs tuples though, so maybe a `tuple(i.strip().split(','))` is needed?

Comment: Sorry I've only seen NOW the square brackets were not round, I should change my glasses